# Appropriate for code-bowling?

Tags: discussion

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=code-bowling

Note that StackOverflow has a few code bowling questions.  Code bowling:

> Code-Bowling is a challenge for writing the most obscure, unoptimized, horrific and bastardized code possible. Basically, the exact opposite of Code-Golf.

By definition, they don't belong on code-golf because it's an opposite.  However they don't belong on StackOverflow either.

What to do? There isn't an area51 site that I can find on it.

Comment: "obscure, unoptimized, horrific and bastardized" sounds extremely appropriate for golfed code.

Answer (score 8):

This site is for many kinds of programming puzzles, and [code bowling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-bowling) is not automatically excluded.

The great difficulty with [code-bowling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-bowling) is one of finding a **"An *objective* primary winning criterion"** as per the [FAQ](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/faq) in light of the fact that just throwing bigger identifiers and lots of NOPs doesn't make anyone very happy. I'm not a fan of them and haven't seen one I considered *good* yet.

We (the moderators) have not been closing them preemptively, but ...

Comment: +1 If the community likes the question and puts some effort into answers, it's unlikely to be closed. But I don't think I have ever seen a _good_ winning criterion specified for code-bowling

Answer (score 3):

I believe that it is okay to have code-bowling contests here, since this site seems to  include other types of challenges, such as king-of-the-hill competitions and fastest-code competitions. Other examples include "Adding without + or -" and "best lossless text compression". I really like the variety in contests because it makes this place more interesting, and more fun.