# Anti-golf questions

Tags: discussion

Would it be acceptable to ask questions here that ask for the *biggest* program to solve a problem, for some measure of big: characters, lines, bytes in memory etc.? And what sort of constraints would be necessary to avoid trivial near-infinite extensions of the size? For example, simply requiring that each line be unique (after trimming whitespace) and executed would still allow answers enumerating every possible function name and nesting them:

```
def a():
    b()

[…]

def zz[…]zz():
    print('answer')
```

Comment: no, then you could just include very large comments or filler code that does nothing

Comment: This already exists, it's called [tag:code-bowling]. It doesn't work very well though

Comment: This is code-bowling but it never works well, mainly because answers always find loopholes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This already exists. We have a tag called [code-bowling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-bowling), and the wiki says:

> Code-bowling is a competition to solve a particular (usually simple) problem in the most bytes or complexity.

That being said, there are 19 questions tagged with code-bowling, and 8 of them are closed. There are lot's of problems with code-bowling that make it hard to do a good code-bowling challenge. In fact, there have even been discussions about [removing code-bowling](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1661/should-we-kill-code-bowling) from the site.

Now, that doesn't mean "Code-bowling" is off-topic (just yet), but it does mean you should be very careful before posting a code-bowling challenge. There must be some feature in the challenge that inherently restricts how long your code can get. Otherwise, submissions would just add billions and trillions of comments and NOP's, which could continue on indefinitely.

I highly recommend [the sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) before you post any challenges of this type.